# using a noun for adjective purpose

Tags: nouns, adjectives

Please excuse me for this question, but I want to know if I can use a noun as an adjective. For example, I want to say:

> "I hold this mission close to my heart for its goodness."

Is this equivalent to saying:

> "The mission is good that I hold it close to my heart."

But the latter sentence is not so appealing to me. I like the first sentence, but is it correct? That's my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence is correct.  It explains that this mission is deeply important to you, and it explains why (its goodness).

I agree that the second sentence is awkward, and it also does not express the idea well.  It would be better usage to say, "The mission is *so* good that I hold it close to my heart."  But even this, though correct, is not phrased as well as the first one.